# Trouble understanding block device API- any good link?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I really don't know if I'm just not looking in the right places, but I seriously haven't found any clear source on how filesystems interact with the underlying block devices. I understand that there are several layers involved in the process, and if I understand well, it's the `request` method in the device driver that ultimately handles data retrieval/writes. I just don't know how to add these requests to the queue. I do know about the  `block_device_operations` struct, but none of those methods seem to be what I am looking for.

Am I missing anything obvious? I really don't mean to bother anyone, it's just that I cannot find this and I've got pretty much the rest of my (basic) filesystem covered (I've encapsulated all reads/writes in some custom functions which remain unimplemented).

Edit: updated question to make it more specific in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79832/having-trouble-understanding-filesystem-block-dvice-i-o). I've got a better idea of what I need, but there's still plenty of which I don't fully grasp.